# Is floating-point arithmetic distro dependant?

Tags: debian, fedora, distributions, floating-point

I came across [an article in Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/03/how-two-volunteers-built-the-raspberry-pis-operating-system/) about Raspbian that said the primary interest of the developers of it was that they wanted an OS with fully optimized for its floating-point unit, and since Fedora didn't have it they ported Debian to the Raspberry Pi.

How can you tell that a distro is suited (or not) for floating-point arithmetic?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. What is "OS floating-point support" supposed to be? FP operations are done either in hardware or in libraries. None is connected to the OS. You should get precise problem about what is supposed to be the problem before you ask such a question. This preparing question may be on-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You mis-quoted that article a bit - it's support for a specific piece of hardware (a floating point unit) present on that platform that Linux distros in general lack. (@Hauke: not everything's a full-fledged x86_64 with FP, MMX, SSE, ...)

Comment: @Mat I am well aware of that but your platform either has hardware FP or not. It cannot be added by porting a different distro...

Comment: @Hauke: I disagree. A FP unit can be an optional component (either an additional discreet component, or an "option" on the chip die itself). i387 was like that. You (usually) need both kernel _and_ library (and/or compiler) support to make it work properly, so it's a distro/port thing.

Comment: Its both. Obviously, if you don't have hardware support for floating point you have to do it in software. If you do it in software, you have to compile against that architecture, if  you do it in hardware you have to re-compile. So the distro is affected -- it needs to be compiled against the right arch to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ARM hardware, there are two types of floating point operations; those done in software, and those done on hardware. Previous ARM hardware often left out hardware that did floating point and left that work to a virtualized software solution since the performance hit was not that large and the cost of hardware was kept low.

Nowadays many ARM SoCs offer hardware floating point, but this requires a different architecture in the chip itself, therefor all binaries need to be re-compiled. This is why distros, like Debian for example, have an architecture called "armel" and "armhf". They're both floating point capable, but armel does it in software and armhf (i.e. ARM hardfloat) does it in hardware.

In general, you'll want to run your all your binaries under the same architecture, though with Debian multiarch it is possible to have multiple architectures supported and run with qemu, but this is still a bit complicated.

Comment: It isn't “a different architecture in the chip itself”, but a different way of passing arguments to functions (an [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)). Since this affects all library calls, you pretty much have to have a consistent system (every program and library using the armel ABI or every program and library using the armhf ABI).

Comment: Here we are treating with ARM hadware, but I suppose a similar answer applies to other architectures, right? In that case does the "virtualized software solution" changes from distro to distro ? Actually that's my interest right now...how can you tell that one virtualized software solution to the floating-point problem is better than another one?

Comment: Thanks Giles, that was said way better than my description.

Comment: @RubénAlcázar I don't think you can determine if one implementation is better than another at the distro level. I think you won't necessarily need to worry about that though since the distros tend to share this kind of implementation. I know for example that Debian borrowed heavily from Gentoo's implementation of armhf and I strongly suspect there is a bit of Debian influence in the Fedora ARM port.

Comment: Also, there is a cross-distro mailing list for questions on the ARM arch: http://lists.linaro.org/mailman/listinfo/cross-distro